# 'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL' R - PCA and as.matrix

Tags: r, sparklyr

I am doing the simplest example you can find with the `iris` dataframe PCA, but I keep on getting the same error from the PCA matrix:

```
 iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, "iris", overwrite = TRUE)
> pca_model <- tbl(sc, "iris") %>%
+   select(-Species) %>%
+   ml_pca()
> print(pca_model)
Explained variance:

        PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4 
0.924618723 0.053066483 0.017102610 0.005212184 

Rotation:
                     PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
Sepal_Length -0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
Sepal_Width   0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
Petal_Length -0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
Petal_Width  -0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574
> D <- as.matrix(iris[1:4])


> E <- as.matrix(pca_model$components)
Error in array(x, c(length(x), 1L), if (!is.null(names(x))) list(names(x),  : 
  'data' must be of a vector type, was 'NULL'
```

Can someone point out where the mistake is? I can't figure it out. 
Thank you

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stackoverflow. What is `sc` in your example? could you give a `dput()` of it? What package is `ml_pca()` from?

Comment: looks like it's from `sparklyr` ...

Comment: I spent a little while trying to install the toolchain, but it was too much work (sparkly -> JRE -> etc etc)

Comment: its a simple package from R:   
install.packages("sparklyr")
 library(sparklyr) 
spark_install()
sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short-ish answer to your problem is that `ml_pca` returns a model object not a results object (these are not strictly offical terms). If you inspect `pca_model` you will see that (e.g. `str(pca_model)`). You can think of `pca_model` as being more like the return from `lm` than `prcomp` for example... Basically, what you need to do is use the model to 'predict' (I put this in quotes as opposed to backticks, because it turns out you cannot use `ml_predict` in this case, not sure why) with the same data you trained to get your desired output. For `ml_pca_models` there are some convenient wrapper functions `tidy`, and `augment` then will get you where you need to go. **NB:** How we are suppose to know that augment means predict and tidy means gather components is beyond me.

Wasn't sure if you wanted the components (i.e. loadings) or the rotations so I am giving you both.

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
install.packages("sparklyr")
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)
sc <- spark_connect(method="databricks") ##change this to for your cluster/spark deployment

iris_tbl <- copy_to(sc, iris, "iris", overwrite = TRUE)
pca_model <- tbl(sc, "iris") %>%
   select(-Species) %>%
   ml_pca()
print(pca_model)
# Explained variance:
#
#         PC1         PC2         PC3         PC4 
# 0.924618723 0.053066483 0.017102610 0.005212184 
# 
# Rotation:
#                      PC1         PC2         PC3        PC4
# Sepal_Length -0.36138659 -0.65658877  0.58202985  0.3154872
# Sepal_Width   0.08452251 -0.73016143 -0.59791083 -0.3197231
# Petal_Length -0.85667061  0.17337266 -0.07623608 -0.4798390
# Petal_Width  -0.35828920  0.07548102 -0.54583143  0.7536574

class(pca_model)
#[1] "ml_model_pca" "ml_model"   

str(pca_model)
#List of 8
# $ pipeline_model    :List of 5
#  ..$ uid       : chr "pipeline_9bc1b484009"
#  ..$ param_map : Named list()
#  ..$ stages    :List of 2
#  .. ..$ :List of 3
#  .. .. ..$ uid      : chr "vector_assembler_9bc188edeed"
#  .. .. ..$ param_map:List of 3
#  .. .. .. ..$ input_cols    :List of 4
#  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Sepal_Length"
#  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Sepal_Width"
#  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Petal_Length"
#  .. .. .. .. ..$ : chr "Petal_Width"
#  .. .. .. ..$ output_col    : chr "assembled9bc3ab7e7e1"
#  .. .. .. ..$ handle_invalid: chr "error"
#  .. .. ..$ .jobj    :Classes 'spark_jobj', 'shell_jobj'  
#  .. .. ..- attr(*, "class")= chr [1:3] "ml_vector_assembler" "ml_transformer" "ml_pipeline_stage"
#  .. ..$ :List of 5
#  .. .. ..$ uid               : chr "pca_9bc60d84696"

loadings <- tidy(pca_model)
loadings

# A tibble: 4 x 5
#  features         PC1     PC2     PC3    PC4
#                    
#1 Sepal_Length -0.361  -0.657   0.582   0.315
#2 Sepal_Width   0.0845 -0.730  -0.598  -0.320
#3 Petal_Length -0.857   0.173  -0.0762 -0.480
#4 Petal_Width  -0.358   0.0755 -0.546   0.754

rot <- augment(pca_model, iris_tbl) %>% collect() #augment predicts given a model and "new" data.
rot
# A tibble: 150 x 9
#   Sepal_Length Sepal_Width Petal_Length Petal_Width Species   PC1   PC2   PC3
#                                      
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2 setosa  -2.82 -5.65 0.660
# 2          4.9         3            1.4         0.2 setosa  -2.79 -5.15 0.842
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2 setosa  -2.61 -5.18 0.614
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2 setosa  -2.76 -5.01 0.600
# 5          5           3.6          1.4         0.2 setosa  -2.77 -5.65 0.542
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4 setosa  -3.22 -6.07 0.463
# 7          4.6         3.4          1.4         0.3 setosa  -2.68 -5.24 0.374
# 8          5           3.4          1.5         0.2 setosa  -2.88 -5.49 0.654
# 9          4.4         2.9          1.4         0.2 setosa  -2.62 -4.75 0.611
#10          4.9         3.1          1.5         0.1 setosa  -2.83 -5.21 0.829
# ... with 140 more rows, and 1 more variable: PC4
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate your time!